# Как запросить List<int> в Main C#

Tags: c#, list

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] myArray = new int[20];
            Random rand = new Random();
            
            for (int x = 0; x < myArray.Length; x++)
            {
                myArray[x] = rand.Next(20);
                Console.WriteLine("Значение элемента массива " + x + " = " + myArray[x]);
            }

            int result = delete(myArray, 5);
            Console.WriteLine("Индексы пятерок: " + result);

            remove(ref myArray, result);
          
        }

        static public List<int> delete(int[] myArray, int value)
        {

           List<int> spisok = new List<int>();

           for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
           {
               if (myArray[i] == value)
               {
                    spisok.Add(i);
               }

           }
            
            return spisok;
        }

        static void remove(ref int[] array, int index)
        {
            int[] newArray = new int[array.Length - 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                newArray[i] = array[i];

            for (int i = index + 1; i < array.Length; i++)
                newArray[i - 1] = array[i];

            array = newArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is
a random array of 100 elements, the delete function searches for indexes of fives and writes them to List<int>, and the remove function removes them from the array, the problem is that it is not possible to output from the List<int> function in Main.

Comment: int result = delete(myArray, 5);  - Ошибку указывает на эту строку

Comment: Поставьте тег языка. `C#`? Дополнительную информацию добавьте в вопрос через кнопку [edit], не оставляйте ее в комментариях. На русском.

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях, пишите в сам пост, а комментарии удалите. Попутно переведите на русский свой комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Индексы пятерок: " + string.Join(", ", result));
```